# Git commit metadata change history

Tags: git, metadata, git-commit

In Git it's possible to change a commit metadata (like the username and email for the author of the commit).

My question is: Is it possible to find out if metadata of some commit was changed? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: In fact, as RomainValeri points out, it's *not* possible to *change* the commit metadata. You can only *copy* the commit to a new, different commit that has different metadata and/or a different source tree. You then have to pull a bit of sleight-of-hand to make people look at the new copy instead of the original: but anyone who is really paying attention can see that your replacement is not the original.

Answer (score 2):

If *anything* in a given commit is changed, whether it's the content of any file, the author name, the date, message, or parent ref(s), the commit hash will be different and any further history also, since children commits will mention this one's hash as their parent reference.

If you want to know if a commit "changed", you need to check if its hash changed at some point.